# Extract hour and minutes from timestamp but keep it in datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe looking like this

```
   open  Start show Einde show
5   NaN     11:30   NaN
6   16:00   18:00   19:45
7   14:30   16:30   18:15
8   NaN     NaN      NaN
9   18:45   20:45   22:30
```

These hours are in string format and I would like to transform them to datetime format.
Whenever I try to use `pd.to_datetime(evs['open'], errors='coerce')` (to change one of the columns) It changes the hours to a full datetime format like this: `2020-04-03 16:00:00` with todays date. I would like to have just the hour, but still in datetime format so I can add minutes etc.

Now when I use `dt.hour` to access the hour, it return a string and not in `HH:MM` format.

Can someone help me out please? I'm reading in a CSV through Pandas `read_csv` but when I use the date parser I get the same problem. Ideally this would get fixed in the `read_csv` section instead of separately but at this point I'll take anything.

Thanks!

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(evs['open']).dt.time`

Comment: @Chris Thanks, this gives me a ```16:00:00``` format but I would like to get rid of the seconds

Comment: I do not think you can strip the seconds off and maintain a type of `datetime.time`  because `16:00:00` is just `datetime.time(16, 0)` You can convert to a string if you want to format it to `%H:%M`: `pd.to_datetime(evs['open']).dt.strftime('%H:%M')`

Comment: @Chris ok thanks! I was looking for something close to R's Lubridate package. Guess I will have to keep the seconds. Do you have any idea how to parse the dates to this format in the ```read_csv``` function? Because I still get the full date/time when using ```parse_dates```

Comment: I do not think you can use the `parse_dates` param because of the way the file is formatted; however, if all your columns are times (like in your sample data) you can stack and unstack after you read the file into memory: `pd.to_datetime(df.stack()).dt.time.unstack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris commented, it is not possible to convert just the hours and minutes into datetime format. But you can use timedeltas to solve your problem.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def to_timedelta(date): 
    date = pd.to_datetime(date)
    try:
        date_start = datetime.datetime(date.year, date.month, date.day, 0, 0)
    except TypeError:
        return pd.NaT # to keep dtype of series; Alternative: pd.Timedelta(0)
    return date - date_start


df['open'].apply(to_timedelta)
```

Output:

```
5        NaT
6   16:00:00
7   14:30:00
8        NaT
9   18:45:00
Name: open, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Now you can use datetime.timedelta to add/subtract minutes, hours or whatever:

```
df['open'] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
```

Output:

```
5        NaT
6   16:15:00
7   14:45:00
8        NaT
9   19:00:00
Name: open, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Also, it is pretty easy to get back to full datetimes:

```
df['open'] + datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 4)
```

Output:

```
5                   NaT
6   2020-04-04 16:00:00
7   2020-04-04 14:30:00
8                   NaT
9   2020-04-04 18:45:00
Name: open, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```